# Can I parse PDF file for scraping?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I have been trying to understand the structure of Scrapy. I just start using Scrapy with selenium for CSS-HTML. I also have to parse some PDFs to scrape and mine the data. Even though I convert pdf to HTML at some converter websites, I couldn't parse it properly.

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:132px;left:334px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft20"><b>MUAM.</b></p>
```

Here I have **"ft20"** class and I supposed to mine *"MUAM."*

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:148px;left:338px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft20"><b>ADET</b></p>
```

And here I have again **"ft20"** class in the same **"DİV"** or **"SPAN"** but I need a table with this information.

So the question is what should I use to Scrape the PDF file properly. Also, do you guys have any suggestions for converting from PDF to HTML?

I would love you to share what I missed and should know for the beginning.

Comment: sharing the sample pdf or url to pdf would be helpful to check on this

Comment: This is the pdf link that I want to parse and get the data to my table row by row.
[link](https://itb.org.tr/dosya/bulten/20200807-tescil-bulteni-1.pdf?v=1597057416153)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with `tabula` library:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"): 
    print(file)
tabula.convert_into(file, "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

this code make a CSV file from pdf